# Centering the checkbox in a line

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I would like to center the checkbox in a line with text next to it.

I've tried already `style="text-align: center;"` in `<div>` but it doesn't work.

```css
input {
  font-size: 16px;
}

label {
  font-size: 11px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

form {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: white;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .5s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)
}

input:checked[type="checkbox"] {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-box__form form">
  <input type="e-mail" name="e-mail" id="e-mail" placeholder="e-mail" />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" />
  <button>Create account</button>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="consent" id="consent" />
    <label for="consent">I agree to whatever you want me to agree</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

At the moment it looks like this in the attached picture. So can someone please guide me on how to center the checkbox in a line?
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeuQ8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `position:relative` and `bottom:**px` as per your need

```css
input {
    font-size: 16px;
}

label {
    font-size: 11px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

form {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    width:15px;
    height: 15px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: white;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: .5s;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    margin:0;
    bottom:-3.5px;
    position:relative
    
    
}

input:checked[type="checkbox"] {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-box__form form">
    <input type="e-mail" name="e-mail" id="e-mail" placeholder="e-mail"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <button>Create account</button>
    <div style="text-align: center;display:inline;">
   <input type="checkbox" name="consent" id="consent" >
    <label for="consent" > I agree to whatever you want me to agree</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @mkre7 Glad that I coud help you.Please upvote and accept my answer if you feel that as helpful. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Just put the checkbox in the tag and use

```
display: flex; 
align-items: center;
```

on the label

```css
input {
  font-size: 16px;
}

label {
  font-size: 11px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

form {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: white;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .5s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)
}

input:checked[type="checkbox"] {
  background-color: transparent;
}

label {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-box__form form">
  <input type="e-mail" name="e-mail" id="e-mail" placeholder="e-mail" />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" />
  <button>Create account</button>
  <div>    
    <label for="consent"><input type="checkbox" name="consent" id="consent" />I agree to whatever you want me to agree</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add below line only your css class, not need to change in html you written:

```
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
```

```css
input {
    font-size: 16px;
}

label {
    font-size: 11px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

form {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: white;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: .5s;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
}

input:checked[type="checkbox"] {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-box__form form">
    <input type="e-mail" name="e-mail" id="e-mail" placeholder="e-mail"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <button>Create account</button>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="consent" id="consent"/>
    <label for="consent">I agree to whatever you want me to agree</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `align-items` property.

```
div { display: flex; align-items: center; } //immediate parent of checkbox and label
```

Comment: I've already used that

Comment: I have revised my answer, give `display: flex` property to immediate parent of checkbox and label.

Answer (score 1):

For parent div of input add the below style          property

```
.div{
Display:inline-flex;
}

Or you can add the below code
 <label for="input" ><input  type="checkbox" name="input" /></label>
```